# hide the navigation bar "more" button at the bottom of the screen on Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity

On my application, I have, on some devices (such as the HTC One) a bar containing only the "More" button (e.g : three vertical dots). Example below with the Amazon app that gets the same behavior.

[image: Three dots appear]

I tried to remove it, by adding this on my manifest :

```
<application
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > </application>
```

It didn't work. I also tried to change the visibility of the displayed view :

```
View v = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

But it only works when displaying the activity. When I interact on my view, the navigation bar reappers.

I noticed that this navigation bar does not appear on a Galaxy S III nor on a Galaxy S II. Can this navigation bar only be displayed only because of the large resolution of the HTC One screen ?

Is there any way to remove this bar only when it appears ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to be 14 or higher. See [this blog post of mine](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html) from a year or so ago for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but setting to minSdkVersion=14 does not remove the menu button ... did I miss something ?

Comment: My bad, I set android:minSdkVersion to 14 and not android:targetSdkVersion

Comment: Works but i need use `android:targetSdkVersion=10`. Any Idea?

Comment: @annelorayne: My suggestion would be for you to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain why you think you need `android:targetSdkVersion=10`, so that you can get help in fixing that. Nobody should be using `android:targetSdkVersion=10` at this point.